# MOSFET has constant current

Tags: mosfet, batteries

I have the following simple circuit. However, when I put the multimeter on the receiving end I'm always getting a current and I can't shut the gate, can anyone help please?

I'm using the following MOSFET: Infineon AUIRL1404Z N-channel MOSFET Transistor, 180 A, 40 V, 3-Pin TO-220AB

Power source is an 11.1V 5000mAh LiPo battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZhsFA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have no gate discharge resistor. Add a resistor 10-100k at the gate to ground, problem solved.

Comment: Resistor gate to source as el Captain says.

Comment: In your previous question you had a battery voltage of 22V, is that still the case? The mosfet you have has a max Vgs of 16V.

Comment: You can flip components in Circuit Lab. I cleaned up your schematic and added component / Power source info to it.

Comment: @SteveG Yes previously I had two 11.1 LiPo's in serial, and a voltage regulator to step that down to 5v for the gate, but for simplicity I've ditched one of the batteries and am just using one, but I'm still having a constant current.

Comment: Sorry @Captainj2001 I'm not following, the gate is only one pin, how would I achieve what you're suggesting as the gate's trigger at the moment is the positive from the battery?

Comment: See Tony's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Shunt Vgs with R1 to turn off. Never leave floating.

Also , FYI, Keep power + and return - paths close together as in paired wires or twisted wires and never in a large loop as shown in a "logic diagram".

Comment: Great! Thank you, I'll try that. Incidentally, I know you suggest a 10kohm resister, but you couldn't link to it on rscomponents.co.uk for me could you please? Just so as I get the right thing... :)

Comment: http://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/passive-components/fixed-resistors/through-hole-fixed-resistors/?searchTerm=10k  cheapest will work if you followed my advice